# Why I get these errors after Parrot OS loads?

Tags: linux, ssd, parrot-os

I have Parrot OS on External SSD (WD My Passport). It boots up, Presents Parrot's loading screen and then I get 3 messages

```
[5.797031] scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page: asked for 1 got 0
[5.797374] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[5.797424] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
```

After this I get only black screen and nothing else.

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: No. Sadly not. But I will keep it going. As soon as I get new info I will post here :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu with WD too! All posts I've read on different forums have no answer. I however can boot and everything works, just curious because I got so many errors one of which was this. Kernel 5-0-0-27

Comment: Yeah.. Same here.. If I may ask for a favour.. Everything you find out about error post it here

Comment: Will do as soon as I do figure out.

Comment: Okay. Awesome. Let's try and figure this out